# How do I put put fira code font in neovim?

Tags: vim, neovim, fira-code

I recently found out about fira code and I was wondering how do I get it in neovim?

I didnt find any tutorial

Comment: Are you using nvim in terminal or you are using some GUI for nvim? Please add the relevant information for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about nvim-qt and not in your terminal, on Windows, in my **$HOME\AppData\Local\nvim** folder, I have **ginit.vim** file with the following content :

> GuiFont! Fira Mono:h11:cANSI:qDRAFT

guifont is an option to force the font used in gvim normally, but nvim-qt seems to follow it as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the terminal font.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your font is not configured in Neovim. The text editor uses the font defined for your terminal (xterm, Gnome Terminal, Kitty, Alacritty...)

Comment: Maybe they were talking about neovim-qt